# How do you get a linked message in discord.js?

Tags: discord.js

I want to add a mod command to my discord.js bot that adds a message to the starboard. The way I want it to work is if someone types in !mod starboard _____ (message link) the linked message will be added to the starboard. I know how to add that message to the starboard once I have it but I don't know how to get the message. The code below is what I have so far, but it says it can't read "first" of "undefined." What is the proper syntax?

`const targetmessage = message.mentions.message.first();`

Answer (score 1):

This is the way message links work:

```
https://discord.com/channels/guildId/channelId/messageId
```

Use simple regex to get each id

```js
// "link" is the message link which you have to get on your own
const ids = link.match(/\d+/g)
const message = await client.channels.cache.get(ids[1])?.messages.fetch(ids[2]).catch(err => null) ?? null
```

This returns the message if found, or null if not. Replace `client` with the guild you want if it needs to be guild specific.

Comment: The error I'm getting is "await is only valid in async function". Also, the question marks have red error lines under them.

Comment: Make the callback async

Comment: That didn't work but I used your code to change my code to read what is below. Do you know why it would return a fetchedMsgs is not defined error?

```else if (args [0] === `starboard`) {
        const link = args[1]
        const ids = link.match(/\d+/g)
        const guild = message.guild;
        guild.channels.cache.get(ids[1]).messages.fetch().then(fetchedMsgs => {
          return fetchedMsgs.find(i => i.id === ids[2])
        }).then(fetchedMsgsFound => {
          console.log(fetchedMsgs.content)```

Comment: @tpoodle1 in the first `then` you return the result of `fetchedMsgs.find(...)` which is a `Message` object. But then you called `.then` again outside the scope of `fetchedMsgs` inside the scope of `fetchedMsgsFound`. So `fetchedMsgs` should be undefined. You'll want to use `fetchedMsgsFound` inside the second `.then`.

Comment: @mswgen the second .then has fetchecMsgsFound. Sorry, I'm a bit confused about what exactly you're reccomending.

Comment: @tpoodle1 so simply in the last `console.log` replace `fetchedMsgs.content` to `fetchedMsgsFound.content`